# readFragment causing IntrospectionFragmentMatcher error although not using interface or unions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am getting the following error when attempting to fetch a query fragment:

> "You are using the simple (heuristic) fragment matcher, but your queries contain union or interface types. Apollo Client will not be able to accurately map fragments. To make this error go away, use the `IntrospectionFragmentMatcher` as described in the docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/fragment-matching.html"

This is the call that triggers the error.

```
const sourceData = cache.readFragment({
        id: `${typename}:${idToAdd}`,
        fragment: gql`
          ${sourceFragment}
        `,
      });
```

where sourceFragment is

```
fragment series on PriceSeries {
    id
    title
    description
    commodity
    region
    location
    isDiscontinued
    order
}
```

Apollo seems to be classing the return value of the fragment as a union or interface. I don't think adding the IntrospectionFragmentMatcher should be necessary as we have no need of unions or interfaces, although maybe I'm wrong. Adding `__typename` to the fragment didn't help.

- How do I remove this error (I may just be missing some gql syntax for typing?)
- Does using fragments mean we should set up the `IntrospectionFragmentMatcher` regardless.. (the docs say it should only be needed `when using fragments on interfaces or unions` which we are not)
- Is the error a bug, should I just be hiding the error (it does work as is if you ignore it)

*Update*

ApolloClient is created as follows

```
 client = new ApolloClient({
      link: createLink('MY_URL', Apollo.fetch),
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });
```

Comment: Can you please share the code of creating `InMemoryCache` instance?

Comment: @User97 I've added the code above, its currently got no custom configuration

Comment: Okay, I don't see any reason for it to throw error in that case as long as `${typename}` is passed correctly.

Comment: Are you writing directly to cache in your code using `writeQuery`, `writeFragment ` or `writeData`? If so, are you omitting writing the `__typename` when you do so?

Comment: The error is being thrown when calling `readFragment' so before any write calls. I've tried removing them all and still get the same message

Comment: Have you tried creating your apollo client with these opts `{
    dataIdFromObject: obj => obj.id,
    addTypename: false,
    fragmentMatcher: {
      match: ({ id }, typeCond, context) => !!context.store.get(id)
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the apollo cache and setup normalization features with `dataIdFromObject`.

```
import { InMemoryCache, IntrospectionFragmentMatcher } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const fragmentMatcher = new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
  // Here you may want to pass your introspection query result data,
});

const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  dataIdFromObject: o => o.id,
  fragmentMatcher,
});
```